# T-SQL Getting Last Value for a Given Group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get the last value in a group of values (a partition), but am having a little trouble. In the example below, you can see an example data set I'm working with. MAX() won't work as the "last" one here is the one with the last date in the partition (ID). I have LAST_VALUE commented out in the query below, but that seemingly doesn't work either... not sure what I'm doing wrong. What I'd like is a result data-set like this:

[image: result data-set]

```
create table #Example (ID int, [Date] datetime, Rating tinyint)

insert into #Example (ID, [Date], Rating)
values
    (5227,  '2021-01-11 19:21:39.107',  1)
    ,(128,  '2020-06-16 17:32:15.653',  5)
    ,(128,  '2020-06-23 11:35:16.570',  1)
    ,(2038, '2020-09-14 13:13:48.253',  2)
    ,(1268, '2020-07-30 16:05:07.950',  0)
    ,(2398, '2020-09-30 13:51:21.813',  5)
    ,(2058, '2020-09-14 13:13:48.253',  1)
    ,(3396, '2020-11-05 12:04:16.043',  5)
    ,(3396, '2020-12-07 13:23:05.357',  3)
    ,(3148, '2020-11-05 12:04:16.043',  1)
    ,(3399, '2020-11-06 12:04:16.043',  2)
    ,(3399, '2020-12-08 13:23:05.357',  4)

select
    exm.ID
    , exm.Date
    , exm.Rating
    --, LAST_VALUE(exm.Rating) over (partition by exm.ID order by exm.Date) as [FinalRating]
from 
    #Example as exm

drop table #Example
```

I'd be greatly appreciative of any assistance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a slight modification to your query will work:

```
create table #Example (ID int, [Date] datetime, Rating tinyint)

insert into #Example (ID, [Date], Rating)
values
    (5227,  '2021-01-11 19:21:39.107',  1)
    ,(128,  '2020-06-16 17:32:15.653',  5)
    ,(128,  '2020-06-23 11:35:16.570',  1)
    ,(2038, '2020-09-14 13:13:48.253',  2)
    ,(1268, '2020-07-30 16:05:07.950',  0)
    ,(2398, '2020-09-30 13:51:21.813',  5)
    ,(2058, '2020-09-14 13:13:48.253',  1)
    ,(3396, '2020-11-05 12:04:16.043',  5)
    ,(3396, '2020-12-07 13:23:05.357',  3)
    ,(3148, '2020-11-05 12:04:16.043',  1)
    ,(3399, '2020-11-06 12:04:16.043',  2)
    ,(3399, '2020-12-08 13:23:05.357',  4)

select
    exm.ID
    , exm.Date
    , exm.Rating
    , last_value(exm.Rating) over (partition by exm.id order by exm.date
                                          rows between current row and unbounded following) as [FinalRating]
from 
    #Example as exm
order by id, date
```

Comment: Awesome, this did work, thank you! Can you tell me more about what "rows between current row and unbounded following" does?

Comment: There's a lot of information out there on the web regarding this. But basically in this scenario, it's widening the window that the partition is looking at. By default (the way you initially had it), the partition was limited to the current row... You can also specify a number of rows for the window to look forward (or backward). Hope that helps. If not, just google it and you'll come up with something that explains better.